# Trouble using pandas df.rolling() with my own functions

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I have a pandas dataframe raw_data with two columns: 'T' and 'BP':

```
              T       BP
0        -0.500  115.790
1        -0.499  115.441
2        -0.498  115.441
3        -0.497  115.441
4        -0.496  115.790
...         ...      ...
647163  646.663  105.675
647164  646.664  105.327
647165  646.665  105.327
647166  646.666  105.327
647167  646.667  104.978

[647168 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to apply the Hodges-Lehmann mean (it's a robust average) over a rolling window and create a new column. Here's the function:

```
def hodgesLehmannMean(x): 
    m = np.add.outer(x, x)
    ind = np.tril_indices(len(x), 0)
    return 0.5 * np.median(m[ind])
```

I therefore write:

```
raw_data[new_col] = raw_data['BP'].rolling(21, min_periods=1, center=True, 
                             win_type=None, axis=0, closed=None).agg(hodgesLehmannMean)
```

but I get a string of error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\tkpme\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\tkpme\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\tkpme\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\tkpme\OneDrive\Documents\Work\CMC\BP Satya and Suresh\Code\Naveen_peak_detect test.py", line 227, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\tkpme\OneDrive\Documents\Work\CMC\BP Satya and Suresh\Code\Naveen_peak_detect test.py", line 75, in main
    raw_data[new_col] = raw_data['BP'].rolling(FILTER_WINDOW, min_periods=1, center=True, win_type=None,
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1961, in aggregate
    return super().aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 523, in aggregate
    return self.apply(func, raw=False, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1987, in apply
    return super().apply(
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1300, in apply
    return self._apply(
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 507, in _apply
    result = calc(values)
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 495, in calc
    return func(x, start, end, min_periods)
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1326, in apply_func
    return window_func(values, begin, end, min_periods)
  File "pandas\_libs\window\aggregations.pyx", line 1375, in pandas._libs.window.aggregations.roll_generic_fixed
  File "c:\Users\tkpme\OneDrive\Documents\Work\CMC\BP Satya and Suresh\Code\Naveen_peak_detect test.py", line 222, in hodgesLehmannMean
    m = np.add.outer(x, x)
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 705, in __array_ufunc__
    return construct_return(result)
  File "C:\Users\tkpme\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 694, in construct_return
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

which appear to be driven by the line

```
m = np.add.outer(x, x)
```

and points to something not being implemented or numpy being missing. But I import numpy right at the beginning as follows:

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd
```

The function works perfectly well on its own if I feed it a list or a numpy array, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Interestingly, if I use the median instead of the Hodges-Lehmann Mean, it runs like a charm

```
raw_data[new_col] = raw_data['BP'].rolling(21, min_periods=1, center=True, 
                             win_type=None, axis=0, closed=None).median()
```

What is the cause of my problem, and how do I fix it?

Sincerely

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code with a small dataframe and it worked well, so maybe there is something on your dataframe that must be cleaned or transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It turns out that

```
 m = np.add.outer(x, x)
```

requires x to be array like. When I tested it using lists, numpy arrays, etc. it worked perfectly, just as it did for you. But the `.rolling` line generates a slice of a dataframe, which is not array like, and the function fails with a confusing error message. I modified the function to create a numpy array from the input and it now works as it should.

```
def hodgesLehmannMean(x):
    x_array = np.array(x)
    m = np.add.outer(x_array, x_array)
    ind = np.tril_indices(len(x_array), 0)
    return 0.5 * np.median(m[ind])
```

Thanks for looking at it!